# Is it possible to add mailto link inside custom bootbox?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootbox

I was wondering if it was possible to add `<a href="mailto:someone@yoursite.com">Email Us</a>` to a custom bootbox? I would like the user to have the option of clicking email link. I'm currently using:

```
function dbError() {
var box = bootbox.dialog({
    message: "There is currently a problem when trying to connect to the Database. Please try again or contact "'<a href="mailto:someone@yoursite.com">Email Us</a>'" to resolve this issue if it persists.",
    title: "Database Error"
});
box.find('.modal-title').css({ 'color' : 'red' });
};
```

This works OK, if I remove the `<a href="mailto:someone@yoursite.com">Email Us</a>`. Any help or suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It would be useful to also include some demo html code so other people can easily copy/paste your example to get a faster turnaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your message string is causing the error - specifically here:

```
"...Please try again or contact "'
```

When you close the double quotes `" "` the javascript reads that as the end of the string and expects a `;` or an `+` otherwise will throw an error.

**Minor fix :)**

```
var a = '<a href="mailto:someone@yoursite.com">Email Us</a>';

var message = "There is currently a problem when trying to connect to the Database." +
    " Please try again or contact " + a + " to resolve this issue if it persists."


var box = bootbox.dialog({
    message: message,
    title: "Database Error"
});
```

Snippet:

```js
var a = '<a href="mailto:someone@yoursite.com">Email Us</a>';


var message = "There is currently a problem when trying to connect to the Database." +
    " Please try again or contact " + a + " to resolve this issue if it persists.";
    

var box = bootbox.dialog({
    message: message,
    title: "Database Error"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://bootboxjs.com/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://bootboxjs.com/bootbox.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- dialog body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>Send Emails to:</div>
            <!-- dialog buttons -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do it by mixing with javascript like this

```
bootbox.alert('after this it will link to mailto: script', function() {
    document.location.href = "mailto:toon@bluewindsolution.com";
});
```